# Filter array based on value inside another array

Tags: javascript

I have an array that consists of objects. Each object has name and an items array. I want to filter based on the id.

```js
const list = [
 {name: "Bob",
  items: [
   {id: 1, color:"blue"},{id: 2, color:"green"}
  ]
 },
 {name: "Kate",
  items: [
   {id: 3, color:"yellow"},{id: 4, color:"pink"}
  ]
 }, 
 {name: "Fred",
  items: [
   {id: 5, color:"purple"}
  ]
 }
]
```

If the id===1, I want it to return the name and items of that array. Something like `list.filter(listItems => listItems.items.filter(item => item.id === 1))` should return

```
name: "Bob",
  items: [
   {id: 1, color:"blue"},{id: 2, color:"green"}
  ]
```

Edited: fixed bug

Comment: Your input's syntax is invalid. Array definitions do not have key-value pairs, only values

Comment: Yes you're right. I edited it to fix the syntax

Comment: can  an `ID` be redundant ? Or filtering based on what ?

Comment: `ID` is unique. Maybe 'filter' is not the right word. I just want it to return the name and all the items if any item contains a specific `ID`

Comment: I see, at a time you only search for one record based on a given `ID` am I right ?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug with the Fred object's item array, it should be:

```
 {
   name: "Fred",
   items: [ {id: 5, color:"purple"} ]
 }
```

Once you have fixed that bug, we can begin trying out filter statements. A quick and dirty one is shown here:

```js
const list = [ {
  name: "Bob",
  items: [ {id: 1, color:"blue"}, {id: 2, color:"green"} ]
}, {
  name: "Kate",
  items: [ {id: 3, color:"yellow"}, {id: 4, color:"pink"} ]
}, {
  name: "Fred",
  items: [ {id: 5, color:"purple"} ]
} ];

const result = list.filter( obj => obj.items.some( item => item.id === 1 ) );
console.log( result );
```

Here I have two arrow functions. The outer one works on [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the objects in the list array. The inner one works on [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on an item in the items array.

Array.prototype.some returns true if at least 1 matching element can be found.

Array.prototype.filter will include the object only if the filter function returns true.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can create a function that uses `Array.prototype.find` to return the first element in the array for which the callback function returns `true` - in this case the callback can contain a for-loop that returns true when it is able to match the `id` you can pass in as the other argument to the function. For example:

```js
const list = [{
    name: "Bob",
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      color: "blue"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      color: "green"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "Kate",
    items: [{
      id: 3,
      color: "yellow"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      color: "pink"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "Fred",
    items: [{
      id: 5,
      color: "purple"
    }]
  }
];

const filterList = (arr, id) => {
  return arr.find(el => {
    for (let i = 0; i < el.items.length; i += 1) {
      if (el.items[i].id === id) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  })
};

console.log(filterList(list, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method to filtrate the inner `array` (that contains the `object`s with `id` and `color`) while looping through the list.

Here's a a function that acceps an `ID` as a parameter and returns the item containing that `ID` or an empty `array` (`[]`) if no match found :

```js
const list = [{
      name: "Bob",
      items: [{
        id: 1,
        color: "blue"
      }, {
        id: 2,
        color: "green"
      }]
    },
    {
      name: "Kate",
      items: [{
        id: 3,
        color: "yellow"
      }, {
        id: 4,
        color: "pink"
      }]
    },
    {
      name: "Fred",
      items: [{
        id: 5,
        color: "purple"
      }]
    }
  ],
  getItem = id => {
    const l = list.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      if (list[i].items.filter(el => {
          return id == el.id;
        }).length)
        return list[i]
    }
    return [];
  };

console.log(getItem(1)); /** Bob's entry **/

console.log(getItem(5)); /** Fred's entry **/
```